# Detalle con SQL - UNION & ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT matricula_veh as 'Identificacion', 
       concat(marca_veh,' ',modelo_veh) as 'InfoName',
       'Vehiculo' KindData 
  FROM vehiculos 
 UNION 
SELECT id_per as 'Identificacion', 
       concat(nom_per,' ',ape_per) as 'InfoName',
       'Usuario' KindData 
  FROM personas 
 UNION 
SELECT id_per_ad as 'Identificacion',
       matricula_veh_ad as 'InfoName',
       'AdminVehiculo' KindData 
  FROM admin_vehiculos 
 UNION 
SELECT id_reg as 'Identificacion',
       nomc_pas_reg as 'InfoName',
       'RegistroViaje' KindData 
  FROM registro_viaje
```

Funciona perfecto, pero quisiera que pudiera organizarsen todos los resultados de forma cronológica, en cada tabla hay una columna en la que se imprime un **TIMESTAMP**. Cómo puedo realizar la consulta entonces?

La organización debe ser global, no tabla por tabla.

Comment: Por qué el voto negativo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Improvisando encontré la solución, la consulta es ahora

```
SELECT matricula_veh as 'Identificacion', 
       concat(marca_veh,' ',modelo_veh) as 'InfoName',
       'Vehiculo' KindData, 
       dato_veh as 'Fecha' 
  FROM vehiculos 
 UNION 
SELECT id_per as 'Identificacion', 
       concat(nom_per,' ',ape_per) as 'InfoName',
       'Usuario' KindData, 
       datoAfiliacion_per as 'Fecha' 
  FROM personas 
 UNION 
SELECT id_per_ad as 'Identificacion',
       matricula_veh_ad as 'InfoName',
       'AdminVehiculo' KindData, 
       dato_ad as 'Fecha' 
  FROM admin_vehiculos 
 UNION 
SELECT id_reg as 'Identificacion',
       nomc_pas_reg as 'InfoName',
       'RegistroViaje' KindData, 
       datoPartida_reg as 'Fecha' 
  FROM registro_viaje 
 ORDER BY Fecha
```

De cada tabla saqué el valor del **TIMESTAMP** a 'Fecha' como columna, y al final agregué **ORDER BY Fecha**, así obtuve los resultados ordenados por fecha de forma global de diferentes tablas :))